# WebAPI controller don't see value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have sendemail controller

Here is interface code

```
  public interface IEmailService
   {
       Task SendEmail(string email, string subject, string message);
   }
```

And here is API controller

```
 [Route("api/send-email")]
[ApiController]
public class EmailController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IEmailService _emailService;
    public EmailController(IEmailService emailService)
    {
        _emailService = emailService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        await _emailService.SendEmail(email, subject, message);
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

Here is code for SendEmail class

```
public class EmailService: IEmailService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public EmailService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task SendEmail(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            var credential = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = _configuration["Email:Email"],
                Password = _configuration["Email:Password"]
            };

            client.Credentials = credential;
            client.Host = _configuration["Email:Host"];
            client.Port = int.Parse(_configuration["Email:Port"]);
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            using (var emailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
                emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(_configuration["Email:Email"]);
                emailMessage.Subject = subject;
                emailMessage.Body = message;
                client.Send(emailMessage);
            }
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I try to check post request via postman and sending this json to this url - `https://localhost:5001/api/send-email`

> {
>       "email": "suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com",
>       "subject": "Get Medicine",
>       "message": null
>   }

But I get error, that email is null. 
Here is screen of mistake

[image]

I can't understand, why? Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you post the exact error and HTTP status code that you get?

Comment: I updated my post. 500 http code. @IlyaChernomordik

Comment: Mostly there's a mistake in the way you are calling the controller from Postman, post the exact url with json data, it is not able to bind due to this

Comment: I updated my post @MrinalKamboj

Comment: Are you passing the Json data as Body, then this needs [FromBody] attribute to bind correctly

Comment: If you are sending the json object is seen in the screenshot then you can't have multiple parameter. It's just one object, that contains the properties email, subject and mail

Comment: In Postman are you setting the header `Content-Type` to `application/json`? Otherwise sending that JSON data to the API controller will result in the values not being binded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the modification, create an entity class with data properties for API:

```
public class Data
{
  public string email {get;set;}
  public string subject {get;set;}
  public string message {get;set;}
}
```

Now change the API service as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmailAsync([FromBody] Data d)
    {
        await _emailService.SendEmail(d.email, d.subject, d.message);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Now your postman service shall work as expected, receiving data from `Request Body`

**EDIT 1**

Following are other options, in case you are keen to send data using query string:

1. `public async Task<string> SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)`  Or
2. `public async Task<string> SendEmailAsync([FromUri]Data d)`

In both the above cases, following query shall work:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/send-email?subject=Get Medicine&email=suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com
```

Though the first one has the priority, and please note, I am not passing message in parameters since its null in your original query and order or parameters could be anything.

As suggested in the discussion, in case `Data` is not explicitly qualified, then its expects Json data as Http Request Body

Comment: You don't really need FromBody for objects I think, it's automatically bound, only value parameters like strings need that

Comment: I can test iit in my understanding it explicitly helps in serialization of json data passed using the request body

Comment: As @IlyaChernomordik said, the model binder will look in the request's body for anything more complicated than base types. The `[FromBody] paramter attribute is redundant in this case.

Comment: I'd name the model anything other than `Data` - how about `Email`?

Comment: @phuzi in this case it could be redundant due to unavailability of other parameters like Uri, but in general helps in segregating from other parameters like when mix is send using Uri and Body, so in general a good practice to define where and how data shall be send to the service. `Data` is just a placeholder shall be appropriately named as per project requirements

Comment: @EugeneSukh, check the Edit 1 it has options using `QueryString` and `FromUri`. You don't need a model class `Data` for `QueryString`. In case of `FromUri `, data can be passed as the `QueryString`. Therefore all options are possible, what ever works

Answer (score 1):

I think POST requests are not bound the same way you would expect GET requests to be bound by default. There are 2 things you can do for that:

1) Create a request object instead of 3 string

```
public class SendEmailRequest
{
    public string Email {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

2) Do FromBody as suggested in the comments

I suggest the former, it is a cleaner way I think and I use that approach in my application.

Comment: I make frombody and now I get this in postman `{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1."]}`

Comment: Try just making a request object as suggested in point one as well, perhaps you body is not a fully valid JSON? You can verify it in some online checker to be sure